# I am working on RoomDatabase using kotlin, I want to delete the selected row in room database

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am working on `RoomDatabase`, I want to delete the selected row in room database.

```
@Dao
interface DataDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from marksheet_table")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): LiveData<List<DataEntity>>

    @Insert
    fun insert(dataentity: DataEntity)

    @Delete
    fun deleteItem(dataentity: DataEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM marksheet_table")
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM marksheet_table WHERE ID = :id") fun deleteById(id:Int)
```